# is there a way to limit run of sql command in case of first condition matched?

Tags: mysql, case

For example I have a query:

```
SELECT  s.e ,
        v.T ,
        v.G ,
        CASE WHEN ( s.a = 'M'
                    AND s.b = 'N'
                    AND s.c = 'O'
                    AND s.d = 'P'
                    AND s.e = 'Q'
                  ) THEN '0'
             WHEN ( s.a = 'M'
                    AND s.b = 'N'
                    AND s.c = 'O'
                    AND s.d = 'P'
                  ) THEN '1'
             ELSE '2'
        END AS type
FROM    table_v AS v
        LEFT OUTER JOIN table_s AS s ON ( v.a = s.a
                                         AND v.b = s.b
                                         AND v.c = s.c
                                       )
WHERE   ( s.a = 'M'
          AND s.b = 'N'
          AND s.c = 'O'
          AND s.d = 'P'
          AND s.e = 'Q'
        )
        OR ( s.a = 'M'
             AND s.b = 'N'
             AND s.c = 'O'
             AND s.d = 'P'
           )
        OR ( s.a = 'M'
             AND s.b = 'N'
           )
```

Is there a way to just NOT run the second OR in WHERE clause if first one was a success. same for the second OR in case first one failed and second was a success then ignore the third statement.  currently I am using a case in SELECT to filter out what I need. In this case I have to loop again after retrieving the resultset based of the values of CASE type which is slowing everything down.

I also looked into doing UNION separately for each of the OR statement but even in that case there is no way to do a "BREAK"

also looked into CASE in where clause but that also slows it down and still gets me multiple results that I don't really need.

Comment: first thing to do is change the join to INNER JOIN because ALL filtering conditions apply to the alias s hence an s row must be present in all results

Comment: oh, and the answer to your specific question is quite simple. No. SQL does not work that way. Please add sample data and expected result to your question because you haven't really told us what is needed except this: "still gets me multiple results that I don't really need."

Answer (score 0):

When you use where clause conditions on a left joined table you override the ability for that table's row to be absent (unless you allow for NULLs). In this case every filtering condition requires that a row from table_s is present and hence you should use the more efficient inner join.

```
FROM    table_v AS v
        INNER JOIN table_s AS s ON ( v.a = s.a
                                         AND v.b = s.b
                                         AND v.c = s.c
                                       )
```

There is no "break" facility within a where clause. However your current conditions don't seem to form exclusive subsets because all of set 1 (M+N+O+P+Q) would fit into set 2 (M+N+O+P) which in turn fits into 3 (M+N)

Do you need additional conditions to make them exclusive?

```
WHERE   ( s.a = 'M'
          AND s.b = 'N'
          AND s.c = 'O'
          AND s.d = 'P'
          AND s.e = 'Q'
        )
        OR ( s.a = 'M'
             AND s.b = 'N'
             AND s.c = 'O'
             AND s.d = 'P'
             AND NOT s.e = 'Q'
           )
        OR ( s.a = 'M'
             AND s.b = 'N'
             AND NOT (
                          s.c = 'O'
                      AND s.d = 'P'
                      AND s.e = 'Q'
                     )
           )
```